# Update variable every x seconds with jquery

Tags: jquery, variables, timeout, setinterval

I want to update a variable on a given time interval with a function. Here's my code:

```
        var heroVel1 = game.currentHero.GetLinearVelocity().x;

        var heroVel2 = '';

        setInterval(function() {
            var heroVel2 = heroVel1;
        }, 2000);

        console.log(heroVel2);
```

I've tried many different solutions with setInterval() and Timeout(), but don't know why it doesn't work.
I want to console.log the changed variable.

I'm a newbie and been stuck with this the whole day. All help/feedback is highly appriciated!!

Comment: Place the console write in the function. Now the variabele is written to the console and the value is changed two seconds later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are defining a new variable inside the setInterval instead of reusing heroVel2..

try:

```
setInterval(function() {
         heroVel2 = heroVel1;
         console.log(heroVel2);
    }, 2000);
```

This should update the heroVel2 in the outer scope aswell as write to the console every 2 seconds.

**UPDATE:**

Ok so based on your comments it has become clear that this is all done in a continous loop, which is why you are getting spammed with console.logs.

What you would do is NOT use setInterval and instead do time comparison. The problem is that when setInterval is called the function inside it is immediately called. So when you execute a setInterval every 10ms, you'll get a console.log every 10ms.

outside of you gameloop define a:

timeLastUpdated = new Date().getTime();

and inside the loop, you would check to see if the currentTime - timeLastUpdated >= 2000 
if it is, then you will set timeLastUpdate to currentTimeMillis. This way you will get an action to happen every 2000ish miliseconds.

```
timeLastUpdated =  new Date().getTime(); // Gets the time in millis


function gameLoop() {    
var currentTimeMillis = new Date().getTime(); // For each trip through this loop, set currentTimeMillis to the currentTime.


if( currentTimeMillis - timeLastUpdated >= 2000) { // has it been more than 2000milis since last?

heroVel2 = heroVel1;
console.log(heroVel2);

    timeLastUpdated = currentTimeMillis;

}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8qabzjy1/7/)

Comment: I've tried to do as you suggested and also put console.log inside the function as @Barry suggested. The result is a long line of values from heroVel1. I just want the updated variable of heroVel2 every 2 seconds in console.log. Does it make sense?

Comment: and putting console.log(heroVel2); inside the setInterval function doesn't do that?

Comment: It doesn't give me an updated variable every 2 seconds as I want. Just a long list of values from `game.currentHero.GetLinearVelocity().x;`. But I just want a single value every 2 seconds.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand. I created a fiddle that console.log's the value every 2 sec. http://jsfiddle.net/8qabzjy1/3/ Check the console to see that a new value is being posted every 2 sec.

Comment: It is exactly what I'm trying to do. But this is what happens:
In console at seems to wait for 2 seconds and then log heroVel2 every mili second??

Comment: Is this entire code run inside a gameloop of some sort?

Comment: Yes, I think I need re-phrase the whole question. Is that possible somehow? It will change the original question.

Comment: Thx a million times. It works as I want it to now. I didn't know that the it made a loop. That got me wrong. Great help and very explanation, thx.

Answer (score 0):

The interval you have provided is updating the value of `heroVel2` every 2 seconds, but nothing else.  If you want the new value to be logged, you must also include the log within the interval.

```
setInterval(function() {
    heroVel2 = heroVel1;
    console.log(heroVel2);
}, 2000);
```

Of course, the value that you are updating it to here doesn't change, since `heroVel1` has not changed.  To ensure you get the updated value, you would have to refetch it from `game.currentHero.GetLinearVelocity().x` like so:

```
setInterval(function() {
    heroVel2 = game.currentHero.GetLinearVelocity().x;
    console.log(heroVel2);
}, 2000);
```

And, depending on the needs of your script, this may make the variables useless, as you could simply pass the current velocity as an argument to `console.log` directly.

Comment: Actually I want to see if `heroVel1 = game.currentHero.GetLinearVelocity().x;`change over time and execute another function if the value has changed.

Comment: Would that not be as simple as `heroVel2 = game.currentHero.GetLinearVelocity().x;` `if(heroVel1 != heroVel2) console.log('heroVel has changed!');` ?

Comment: Almost. I have an input from `game.currentHero.GetLinearVelocity().x;` if that value is the same after 3 seconds, I want to execute new function.